# Periodically update Polymer Binding

Tags: data-binding, polymer

I have a polymer data binding that uses a filter to change a date time into "x minutes ago", or "4 days ago".

The only problem with this approach is that the data can become stale if the user does not reload the screen.

Is there any way that I can force the binding to reevaluate, even though the bound property has not changed?

I can manually do it by increment the tick on the time stamp, but that's just wrong! I can also do it by setting it to something else, then reverting to the correct value. Even worse!

Original binding:

```
{{ comment.createdOn | toLocalFormat('fromNow')}}
```

The toLocalFormat filter simply converts the time into '5 minutes ago', 'yesterday' etc.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I've come up with the best hack yet... setting a timer on the polymer element that increments a ticker. Then, in the binding syntax, reference this ticker as well as the date, forcing Polymer to monitor both values. This way, when the ticker changes every 60 seconds, the binding is updated.

Comment: {{ {createdOn: comment.createdOn, ticker: ticker} | toLocalFormat('fromNow')}}

Comment: Could you post a code snippet of what you have so far or add it to a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Added the binding to original. Unfortunately I can't access jsFiddle

Comment: Apologies as I misunderstood your question initially. I can't think of a solution to this other than what you have done yourself using a timer to update the value.